# Bolt CMS on Vagrant does not parse PHP

Tags: nginx, vagrant, bolt-cms

My vagrant box doesn't parse PHP-files for Bolt CMS.

I'm a dev for years now, been working in Vagrant since about 5 years, and never had serious problems.

I wanted to give Bolt CMS a try, but when I fire my browser to the correct url (http://sallys.local:8000) it always wants to download the index-file (or any other file) instead of parsing it.

My vagrant-box is updated to the latest version 8.10, I use Nginx, but it seems as Nginx isn't called. I activated the acces-log and it shows no entries. For my other projects, same box, it does.

The Nginx-config for this one is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sallys.local;
    root "/home/vagrant/sallys/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php app.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

#    access_log off;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/sallys.local-ssl-acces.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/sallys.local-ssl-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    # DEV
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/sallys.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sallys.local.key;
}
```

I have a similar setup for my other projects, and they all respond on port 8000. And parse PHP-files correctly. This seems to be a noob-problem. But I can't find the problem in here.

when I'm using the built-in server, it does work. So there must be a problem with Nginx.

Any one any idea?

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that is an Nginx site config for a Symfony 2/3 set-up (Symfony 4 is simpler FWIW), so it won't work "out of the box", so to speak.

My guess would be the `location / {}` as that is referencing `app.php`, and by default, a Bolt install will use `index.php` as the index file in the webroot.

There is a [specific documentation page](https://docs.bolt.cm/installation/webserver/nginx) in Bolt's documentation that covers Nginx configuration specifically for a Bolt install, and I'd guess that'd be enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me out, Gawain. I tried your solution, but it didn't work. I removed the entries in my homestead file, reprovisioned vagrant, ..... and it works...

There is a new config generated:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name sallys.local;
    root "/home/vagrant/sallys/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/sallys.local-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/sallys.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sallys.local.key;
}
```